# How to describe Partial Wave Analysis in easy words?

Tags: particle-physics, scattering, elementary-particles

Like the question title says, can anyone describe the fundamental principle of partial wave analysis in easy words? Without equation, just by saying maybe why it is so useful in particle physics and scattering theory?

Answer (score 1):

Scattering problems in particle physics often involve short-range interactions, and physicists primarily care about the asymptotic behavior of the solutions (i.e. what happens far away from the interaction point). Partial wave expansion is a way to rewrite the incoming and outgoing wavefunctions of a short-range scattering interaction in a way that simplifies the analysis of the problem without changing the asymptotic behavior of the solutions.